# How to Display Commas After Every Third Number Without Compromising Calculator

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, calculator

I am trying to create a loan calculator that uses commas to separate every third number. For example, $1,000,000.75.

Is there a way to display all of the input values like this, without compromising the actual calculation of numbers?

Right now, if a comma is entered in any of the inputs, than the calculated input (input that displays the calculation), throws an error (NaN). I am wondering if there is any way to do this using something such as PHP or JavaScript?

Here is a picture of a working example of my loan calculator:

[image]

Here is my full page code for the loan calculator:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    font-family:arial,verdana,sans-serif;
}

img a {
    border:none;
}

img {
    border:none;
}

.bback {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

#image {
    width:84px;
    height:41px;
}

#stretchtable {
     width:60%;
     max-width:500px;
     min-width:200px;
}

.fontwhite {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    border:4px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:left;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> ::: Loan Calculator</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#102540">


 <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function showpay() {
 if ((document.calc.loan.value == null || document.calc.loan.value.length == 0) ||
     (document.calc.months.value == null || document.calc.months.value.length == 0)
||
     (document.calc.rate.value == null || document.calc.rate.value.length == 0))
 { document.calc.pay.value = "Incomplete data";
 }
 else
 {
 var princ = document.calc.loan.value;
 princ = princ.replace(',','');
 var myfloat = parseFloat(princ);
 var term  = document.calc.months.value;
 term = term.replace(',','');
 var myfloat1 = parseFloat(term);
 var intr   = document.calc.rate.value / 1200;
 intr = intr.replace(',','');
 var myfloat2 = parseFloat(intr);
 document.calc.pay.value = (myfloat * myfloat2 / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + myfloat2), myfloat1)))).toFixed(2)

 }

// payment = principle * monthly interest/(1 - (1/(1+MonthlyInterest)*Months))

}

// -->
</script>

<script>
function trimDP(x, dp) {
    x = parseFloat(x);
    if (dp === 0)
        return Math.floor(x).toString();
    dp = Math.pow(10, dp || 2);
    return (Math.floor((x) * dp) / dp).toString();
}


window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.dp2'), i;
    function press(e) {
        var s = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (s === '.')
            if (this.value.indexOf('.') === -1)
                return; // permit typing `.`
        this.value = trimDP(this.value + s);
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    function change() {
        this.value = trimDP(this.value);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
        nodes[i].addEventListener('keypress', press);
        nodes[i].addEventListener('change', change);
    }
});
</script>

<div class="bback">
<h1 style="color:white;font-size:16px;">G.B.M. Trailer Service Ltd. Loan Calculator</h1>
<a href="index.html">
<img src="images/backbutton.png" alt="Back Button" id="image" title="Back"></a><br /><br />
<center>
<div class="fontwhite" style="width:60%;">
The results of this loan payment calculator are for comparison purposes only.
They will be a close approximation of actual loan
repayments if available at the terms entered, from a financial institution. This
is being
provided for you to plan your next loan application. To use, enter values
for the
Loan Amount, Number of Months for Loan, and the Interest Rate (e.g.
7.25), and
click the Calculate button. Clicking the Reset button will clear entered
values.
</div>
</center>
</div>
<p>
<center>
<form name=calc method=POST>
<div style="color:white; font-weight:bold; border:4px grey outset; padding:0px; margin:0px;" id="stretchtable">
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border:1px outset grey">
<tr><th bgcolor="black" width=50%><font color=white>Description</font></th>
<th bgcolor="black" width=50%><font color=white>Data Entry</font></th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="black">Loan Amount</td><td bgcolor="black" align=center><input
type=text name=loan
size=10 class="dp2" onkeyup="format(this)"></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="black">Loan Length in Months</td><td bgcolor="black"
align=center><input type=text
name=months size=10 onkeyup="format(this)"></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="black">Interest Rate</td><td bgcolor="black" align=center><input
type=text name=rate
size=10 onkeyup="format(this)"></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="black">Monthly Payment</td><td bgcolor="black"
align=center><em>Calculated</em> <input
type=text name=pay size=10 class="dp2" onkeyup="format(this)"></td></tr>
<tr><td  bgcolor="black"align=center><input type=button onClick='showpay()'
value=Calculate></td><td bgcolor="black" align=center><input type=reset
value=Reset></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

<div style="width:60%;">
<font size=2 color=white>Enter only numeric values (no commas), using decimal points
where needed.<br>
Non-numeric values will cause errors.</font>
</center>
</div>

<p align="center"><font face="arial" size="-2">This free script provided by</font><br>
<font face="arial, helvetica" size="-2"><a href="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript
Kit</a></font></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for a solution to my problem, as I am not experienced with this type of code. Suggestions may only get me so far.

Thank you for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

`var intr   = document.calc.rate.value / 1200;`

with this

`var intr   = (parseFloat(document.calc.rate.value) / 1200).toString()`

For the adding commas bit, replace this:

`document.calc.pay.value = (princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + intr), term)))).toFixed(2)`

with this

`document.calc.pay.value = (princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + intr), term)))).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()`

there are other ways to do it, but this seems like the fastest way without introducing more functions. JavaScript gives us toLocaleString which should be your most flexible option.

Comment: The `calculated` input still returns `NaN` when the calculate button is hit. `NaN` only appears when a comma is inputted into one of the inputs. I am using `document.calc.pay.value = (princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + intr), term)))).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()`.

Comment: I see, I made the bad assumption that the given code was not return a NaN. Looking at it. Do you have a live URL?

Comment: just to try, replace ```var intr   = document.calc.rate.value / 1200;``` with ```var intr   = (parseFloat(document.calc.rate.value) / 1200).toString()```

Comment: But so you know what to look for: somewhere a string is getting used like a number e.g. "2,222"/12 is NaN... so we try to transform these numbers as strings into real numbers before operating on them.

Answer (score 0):

Before calculation simply use `.replace(',','')` to remove the commas. Then you need to cast it to to a float by using `parseFloat()`. Then when you go to display the numbers you can reformat it with commas if you would like.

```
var mystring = '10,000.12';
mystring = mystring.replace(',','');
var myfloat = parseFloat(mystring);
```

For adding the commas back in you can do something like this:
[How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

From that answer:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question to what I believe you have told me to do, and it still doesn't work. The calculated input remains blank after the calculate button is hit.